# Linkedin search with c# and asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, linkedin-api

I want to create a `search feature for people and company` using the linkedin api.

I've read extensively, but I need to do this in `C# and asp.net`, and I haven't found enough examples regarding the same.

Can someone give some kind of a sample code and what I'll be needing & how I should go about doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recomend you the [LinkedIn Developer Toolkit](http://linkedintoolkit.codeplex.com/) which have built a C# library that wraps the LinkedIn REST API.

Comment: This link has no downloads available.  Depreciated?

Answer (score 0):

A quick search turned up this [c# example](http://developer.linkedin.com/thread/1230)
Have you looked at that one?

Answer (score 0):

[This section describes](https://developer.linkedin.com/apis) JavaScript API and Rest API. JavaScript API enable to build dynamic application in the web browser. REST API provide simple representation of people, companies, jobs, and the interactions and relationships between them.

[Document](https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/people-search-api) describes People Search API which returns information about people.